# XQuartz 2.7.8 crashes on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, xquartz

I've been running XQuartz for years on several macs, but ver since I upgraded my iMac to Yosemite (now at 10.10.2) I can't get XQuartz to run at all.  I've tried re-installing and upgrading XQuartz, even tried the 2.7.8_beta3, but the result is always the same - the upgrade/install itself succeeds, but when I try to launch it, it crashes.  Below I've included the beginning of the error report; I've been messing around with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, it's possible that I've just made matters worse.  Can anyone suggest a way to trouble-shoot this?
Thanks - Ed

```
Process:               X11.bin [2078]
Path:                  /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11
Identifier:            org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           X11.bin [2078]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-02-18 20:01:37.258 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        33386A03-9014-59C0-C36D-8C75B81D38D0


Time Awake Since Boot: 100000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/opt/X11/lib/

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _gll_noop
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL

Binary Images:
       0x100261000 -        0x10026eff7 +libXplugin.1.dylib (1) <11FC918E-BF12-3629-8766-5B89A7B51EC4> /opt/X11/*/libXplugin.1.dylib
```